# どこ and なに in subject questions

Tags: questions

> はい、こちらサービスセンターです。
>
> すみません。コンピューターが壊れてしまったんです。
>
> **どこ**が壊れたんですか。
>
> わかりません。

As far as I understand, the manager is asking what exactly has broken (*which part of the computer is broken?*). If we said 何が壊れたんですか in this situation, would the answer be *the computer*?

When shall we use どこ　and 何　in subject questions?

Comment: Do you have a source for this hypothetical dialogue? It seems a little unnatural.

Comment: @BJCUAI Genki II. Workbook. Lesson 18. Listening Comprehension.

Comment: @BJCUAI what makes it a little unnatural?

Comment: As Sazarando has indicated as well, asking a customer first thing which part of the computer is broken would be an unusual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumptions are correct.

As 何 just means 'what', asking 'What is broken?' would be met with incredulity, as you already told the rep that the computer is broken.

（～の）どこ in cases such as this these, means 'which part of'. In essence, part of the subject is being omitted in the query from the rep. The full sentence would be 「**コンピューターのどこ**が壊れたんですか。」

This use of （～の）どこ is fairly ubiquitous for specifying the part or specific location of something ('Where does it hurt?', 'Which section/area of the park should we meet?', 'What don't you like about me?', etc.)

Answer (score 4):

In this context it would be odd to ask 何が壊れたんですか？ because the answer would obviously be コンピューターです

> **Customer:** My computer is broken.（コンピューターが壊れてしまったんです）
>
> **Service Tech:** What's broken?（何が壊れたんですか？）
>
> **Customer:** I just said it's my computer!（コンピューターだと言ったでしょ？）

A better response would be...

> **Service Tech:** How is it broken? *(What's wrong with it?)*

The way to ask this in Japanese is to use **どこが**壊れたんですか？

- **何が**壊れたんですか？ → What (thing) is broken?
- **どこが**壊れたんですか？ → What ***(about the thing)*** is broken?
- **どのように**壊れたんですか？ → How did (the thing) come to be broken?

You should use どこが when you want to know *"what part of"* or *"in what way"* some state came to be.

- 何が悪いんですか？ → What's bad?
- **どこが**悪いんですか？ → What's bad ***about it***?

--

- 何が分からないの？ → What don't (you) understand?
- **どこが**分からないの？ → ***What part*** don't (you) understand?